# Specifying app startup order with erlang.mk

Tags: erlang, build-tools

I'm trying to convert over from an antiquated, unmaintained build tool to Erlang.mk.  I have a release created using [Erlang.mk][1], but it fails when starting up, I believe because apps are starting up in the wrong order.

How do I specify the startup order of the apps?

I would have thought that it would start up apps in the same order as specified in the `LOCAL_DEPS` variable of the Makefile, but that doesn't seem to be happening.  I've looked everywhere I can in the docs, plus googled, but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 4):

The order doesn't depend on `erlang.mk` but on the Erlang VM itself when it's starting the applications. When [`systools`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/systools.html) is starting a specific application it reads the `.app` file to check which application should have been started beforehand and starts them. Only when all the prerequisite applications have been started successfully the requested application is started. See the [description of the app](http://erlang.org/doc/man/app.html) file.

[Example from here](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/lib/humbundee/src/humbundee.app.src):

```
{application, humbundee,
 [{description, "Humble Bundle downloader written in Erlang"},
  {vsn, "0.0.1"},
  {modules,
   [
    =MODULES=
   ]},
  {registered, [hbd_sup, hbd_get_sup]},
  {applications, [kernel, stdlib, sasl, lager]},
  {mod, {hbd_app, []}}
 ]}.
```

This says that `kernel`, `stdlib`, `sasl`, and `lager` must be started before `humbundee` could be started.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on `.app` file `applications` list. Each application and its dependents are started before continuing to the next one.

Comment: Could you show t it from source code?? Source code can say everything.

Comment: erlang.mk doesn't create the applications in the .app file in any particular order?  I have to go in and hand edit this file?