# Why do library dependencies need to be listed in a project's applications?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

What is the purpose of library dependencies( which only provide functions) being listed as an application?

For example, the [left_pad](https://github.com/folz/left_pad.ex) project recommends that it is included as an application when it only provides a simple function.

```
def application do
  [applications: [:left_pad]]
end
```

Should Elixir packages always be made available as applications? How can a new library developer make their dependency available as an application? What other features does this provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look a this question: [Specifying app startup order with erlang.mk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165942/specifying-app-startup-order-with-erlang-mk/36183109#36183109)

Basically, all applications your application depends on are guaranteed to be started before your application is started.

However, if a function in your application calls another function in a module that hasn't been loaded yet, and the module is in one of the paths returned from [`get_path/0`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#get_path-0), then the VM will automatically load that module anyway.

But, when doing releases with release handler (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196148/elixir-how-can-i-leverage-release-handler/36200483#36200483) for more information and also [Erlang's official documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html)), only specific applications will make its way into the release - those you explicitly specify in the `reltool.config` and those that are dependent upon. If your application uses the library application and you don't list it neither in the application file nor in the release configuration file, it won't be deployed to the production system and your application won't be able to call the function from the library application.

And yeah, as pointed out by **michalmuskala**, the list of dependencies is also a factor for the release handler to consider when it calculates the order in which modules are being reloaded when upgrading releases with [release handler](http://erlang.org/doc/man/release_handler.html).

So, summing up, it's not that important in development environment, but it's a good practice, and it's required if you are doing proper Erlang releases when deploying stuff to production.

Comment: This is not true anymore, Elixir will load it for you as long you don't declare any `applications` on your `application`function. You can read more here: https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.15.4/Mix.Tasks.Compile.App.html

Answer (score 4):

Every runtime dependency should be added to the list of applications. Whether a package provides only functions or runs processes is an implementation detail that should not concern the user.

Furthermore, because Erlang can load code on-the-fly, it is my understanding that adding an application to the list of your dependencies ensures the modules are loaded in the correct order. This is especially important in releases where modules that do not belong to your application or any of the dependencies are not included in the release at all.

As to the question why there are two places you define dependencies: `deps` and `applications`:

- `deps` - are mainly about packages and code that you need to require from elsewhere
- `applications` - is about *runtime* dependencies. It may so happen that you have some compile-time-only dependency declared in `deps`, but since it's not a runtime dependency it does not need to be included in `applications`.